# OpenLDAP passwords extract (mdb)

Tags: database, openldap, text-extraction

Sorry for my bad english. 
Here my trouble: I get the database of OpenLDAP server in lmdb format (/var/lib/ldap/data.mdb) and i need to extract all users data from it (with password hashes). But i can`t find solution for it. If i get data from ldap with ldap-connector, i get normal text information what i need, but there is no users hashes. 
I founded a official lmdb page: http://symas.com/mdb/, but there no utilities, only language connectors. I get python3 connector, and try to work with database by instruction from here: http://lmdb.readthedocs.org/en/release/ but no results :(
Help me please. I need utility or python3/php class for convert all mdb-content in usual text.

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility called `slapcat` that you can run on the commandline of the server as root that will dump all contents of the database in the ldif format (which is [LDAP Data Interchange Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format%20LDAP%20Data%20Interchange%20Format)).

If the config is in it's default place running just the command `slapcat` should write the complete contents to stdout, if you need more info read `man slapcat`.